# Choosing the right structure for storing many values of similar type with varying parameters/properties

Tags: javascript, structure, readability

I'm making a video settings screen for an application and I need a way to store each setting before sending it to a UI manager that will create the HTML elements. I was previously storing them as an array like so:

```
let options = [
            new BoolOption("Ragdolls", 1, "description here"),
            new QualityOption("SkeletalMeshLODBias", 0, "description here"),
            new ResolutionOption("Character Texture Resolution", 4, "description here"),
            new Option("Video Memory Texture Pool", [150, 300, 600], 0, "description here")
        ]
```

Bad side of this approach is that, as there are many types being stored and their parameters don't match, readability is compromised - especially when working with lots of values. With this in mind, I made it an object/dictionary and wrote a function for transforming it back into an array:

```
let optionsDictionary = {
    ragdolls: {
        name: "Ragdolls",
        type: BoolOption,
        defaultIndex: 1,
        description: "description here"
    },
    skeletalMeshLODBias: {
        name: "SkeletalMeshLODBias",
        type: QualityOption,
        defaultIndex: 0,
        description: "description here"
    },
    characterTextureRes: {
        name: "Character Texture Resolution",
        type: ResolutionOption,
        defaultIndex: 4
    },
    texturePool: {
        name: "Video Memory Texture Pool",
        type: Option,
        states: [150, 300, 600],
        defaultIndex: 0,
        description: "description here"
    },
}



let optionsDictionaryToOptionsArray = (optionsDictionary) => {
    let options = []
    for (let key in optionsDictionary) {
        let option
        if (optionsDictionary.hasOwnProperty(key)) {
            let setting = optionsDictionary[key],
                name = setting.name,
                type = setting.type,
                defaultIndex = setting.defaultIndex,
                description = setting.description || ""

            switch (type) {
                case Option:
                    let states = setting.states
                    option = new Option(name, states, defaultIndex, description)
                    break
                case BoolOption:
                    option = new BoolOption(name, defaultIndex, description)
                    break
                case RangeOption:
                    let min = setting.min, 
                        max = setting.max
                    option = new RangeOption(name, min, max, defaultIndex, description)
                    break
                case QualityOption:
                    option = new QualityOption(name, defaultIndex, description)
                    break
                case ResolutionOption:
                    option = new ResolutionOption(name, defaultIndex, description)
                    break
                default:
                    throw new Error()
            }
        }
        options.push(option)
    }
    return options
}
```

But I still feel like it can be further improved or made using a more elegant solution, as the keys in each of the dictionary object properties vary with its `.type`. Maybe I even made it worse with the second approach. Any suggestions?

Comment: It sounds like you are trying to build something that already exists. An ODM like Mongoose would allow you to focus on carving out an awesome app instead of worrying about how to access document definitions of objects.

Answer (score 0):

Your question is subject to bias, I believe, as people may disagree about what looks "nicest". So I'll just mention another formatting option available here: **Constructors accepting parameters via a single Object**:

```
let options = [
  new BoolOption({
    name: 'Ragdolls',
    defaultIndex: 1,
    description: 'description here'
  }),
  new QualityOption({
    name: 'SkeletalMeshLODBias',
    defaultIndex: 0,
    description: 'description here'
  }),
  // ...
  // ...
  // ...
];
```

Switching to this format requires almost no refactoring - for a constructor like:

```
let BoolOption = function(name, defaultIndex, description) {
  // ...
};
```

Just throw in `{` and `}` surrounding the parameters, and all should work the same:

```
let BoolOption = function({ name, defaultIndex, description }) {
  // ...
};
```